# One of the Places received from google place autocomplete is not in English

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

One of the places i receive from google place autocomplete is not in english, i also added the language parameter as english. I have added my code on stackblitz .

The place name is erode arts and science college

Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-6x3u1x?file=app/google-place.component.ts) to the working demo on stackblitz,

Here is the form value,
form value:

```
[![{
  "name": "",
  "addresses": \[
    {
      "street": {
        "placeName": "Erode Arts and Science College",
        "address": "Rangampalayam, ஈரோடு, தமிழ்நாடு 638112, India",
        "city": "ஈரோடு", // city name not in english
        "latitude": 11.3013743,
        "longitude": 77.6982415
      },
      "postcode": ""
    }
  \]
}][1]][1]
```

script tag,

```
<script src='https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en-GB&key=AIzaSyCbMGRUwcqKjlYX4h4-P6t-xcDryRYLmCM'></script>
```

Comment: Sounds like missing translations for certain components of address. You can send feedback to Google to let them know: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612